# Distorted points in a plot

Tags: plotting, graphics

Here are some sample data

```
data3 = {{0, 2.9, 0.6}, {1, 1.8, 0.3}, {2, 0.52, -0.12}, {3, 0.69, 0.22},
         {4, 0.51, 0.45}, {5, 0.75, 0.67}, {6, -0.18, 1.29}, 
         {7, -1.56, 1.66}, {8, -1.05, 0.92}, {9, -0.3, 0.38}, 
         {10, -0.35, 0.07}, {11, 0.7, 1.15}, {12, -0.69, 0.45}, 
         {13, -1.15, 0.47}, {14, -0.65, -0.22}, {15, -0.15, -0.73}, 
         {16, 0.74, -1.07}, {17, 0.46759, -0.80989}};

Nt = Length[data3];
d3 = data3[[All, {2, 3}]];
```

Now let's make a nice plot with them

```
labels = Thread[
Range[Nt] -> (Placed[#, Above] & /@ 
  Join[{Subscript["P", 0]}, 
   Range[Nt - 2], {Subscript["L", "6"]}])];
labels = MapAt[Style[#, 18, Bold, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"] &, 
         labels, {All, 2, 1}];
plot = Show[
Graph[# \[DirectedEdge] # + 1 & /@ Range[Nt - 1], 
VertexCoordinates -> d3, VertexLabels -> labels, 
VertexStyle -> {1 -> Red, Nt -> Blue}], Frame -> True, 
Axes -> True, AxesStyle -> {Dashed, Dashed}, 
FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, RotateLabel -> False, 
LabelStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 20], 
FrameTicks -> Automatic, AspectRatio -> 1, ImageSize -> 550, 
PlotRange -> {{-1.75, 3.1}, {-1.2, 1.95}}]
```

The output is the following

[image]

As you can see, there is something wrong with the points. In particular, all circular points are distorted and look like ellipses. This behavior is directly related with the `PlotRange`. If I set equal ranges to all axes then all points are fine. However I want to use this particular range.

So, how can I have nice circular points using the desired plot range?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: This has more to do with `AspectRatio`;  with `VertexSize -> 0.03 {GoldenRatio, 1}` you can counter the stretching of the plot caused by `AspectRatio->1`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This stretching is due to `AspectRatio`. Let's connect `AspectRatio` with `VertexSize` via defining `ar`:

```
ar = 1;
labels = Thread[
   Range[Nt] -> (Placed[#, Above] & /@ 
      Join[{Subscript["P", 0]}, 
       Range[Nt - 2], {Subscript["L", "6"]}])];
labels = MapAt[Style[#, 18, Bold, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"] &, 
   labels, {All, 2, 1}];
plot = Show[
  Graph[# \[DirectedEdge] # + 1 & /@ Range[Nt - 1], 
   VertexCoordinates -> d3, VertexLabels -> labels, 
   VertexStyle -> {1 -> Red, Nt -> Blue}, 
   VertexSize -> 0.04 {GoldenRatio ar, 1}], Frame -> True, 
  Axes -> True, AxesStyle -> {Dashed, Dashed}, 
  FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, RotateLabel -> False, 
  LabelStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 20], 
  FrameTicks -> Automatic, AspectRatio -> ar, ImageSize -> 550, 
  PlotRange -> {{-1.75, 3.1}, {-1.2, 1.95}}]
```

For a few values of `ar`:

[image]

The value of `0.04` in `VertexSize` may be adjusted accordingly.

Comment: you can use `Scaled` here too.. `VertexSize -> Scaled[{.02, .02}]`

Answer (score 4):

hopefully there is a better solution, but one way is to use `GraphPlot` and make the markers with `Scaled[]` aspect ratio, so that they end up being circles after `Show` imposes the aspect ratio.

```
labels = Thread[
   Range[Nt] -> (Placed[#, Above] & /@ 
      Join[{Subscript["P", 0]}, 
       Range[Nt - 2], {Subscript["L", "6"]}])];
labels = MapAt[Style[#, 18, Bold, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"] &, 
   labels, {All, 2, 1}];
plot = Show[
  GraphPlot[
   Graph[# \[DirectedEdge] # + 1 & /@ Range[Nt - 1], 
    VertexCoordinates -> d3, VertexLabels -> labels, 
    VertexStyle -> {1 -> Red, Nt -> Blue}], 
   VertexRenderingFunction -> ({Blue, EdgeForm[Black], 
       Disk[#, Scaled[{.015, .015}]]} &)], Frame -> True, 
  Axes -> True, AxesStyle -> {Dashed, Dashed}, 
  FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, RotateLabel -> False, 
  LabelStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 20], 
  FrameTicks -> Automatic, ImageSize -> 550, 
  PlotRange -> {{-1.75, 3.1}, {-1.2, 1.95}}, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

note you could just use `GraphPlot` ( without `Show` ) and give `GraphPlot` all the frame directives. Same result though.

Comment: I think `Scaled[]` is the better solution.  (I mean it seems intended to be used this way.)